# Predict via Go with use of model saves as .joblib file

Tags: python, go, machine-learning, scikit-learn, joblib

*A bit of preamble. I'm never an ML-engineer, so I could use incorrect terminology, etc. If so, I'm really sorry.*

We currently have an already trained model in .joblib, and python file to be used for predictions. And what I'm trying to do, is to understand, is it possible to use Go instead of Python, as there is no native Scikit-learn neither Joblib support.

So, figural, the python file looks like the following

```py
file = open("/path/to/model", "rb")
model = joblib.load(file)
inputs = #some array of data to be predicted
model.predict(inputs)
```

Thank you in advance!